# log4j2 LogManager.getLogger() is thread safe?

Tags: java, log4j2

When I to execute following code, the log event is logged only once. I'm using log4j2 logger. But when I use `java.util.logger`, all 3 log events are published successfully.

```
   public class TestLoggingMDC
    {
        public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
        {
            System.setProperty( "log4j.configurationFile", "log4j2.xml" );//set path here to log4j2 config file

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 );
            TestLoggingMDC testLoggingMDC = new TestLoggingMDC();

            for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
            {
                Runnable runnableTask = testLoggingMDC::calculate;
                executor.execute( runnableTask );
            }

            executor.awaitTermination( 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS );

        }

        public void calculate()
        {
            //java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger( "testMDC" ).info( "total is ..." );//this works. log 3 time
            LogManager.getLogger( ).info( "total is ..." );//this does not

        }

}
```

And when I synchronize calculate method `public synchronized void calculate()` or get a class lock, like the following, it works as expected.

```
public  void calculate()
    {
        synchronized ( LogManager.class )
        {
            LogManager.getLogger().info( "total is ..." );
        }

    }
```

log4j2 is thread safe, but it seems `LogManager.getLogger()` is not thread safe? Or am I missing something?

Please note that I tried executing threads without `ExecutorService` (using `java.lang.Thread`), the result is the same.

- log4j2 version 2.7
- IntelliJ Idea 2018.1.5

*log4j2 config file:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %c{36} - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="fileAppender" fileName="out/MDCTest.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%X{id} %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="testMDC" level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="fileAppender"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: This is just for curiosity, right? You're not actually writing `LogManager.getLogger( ).info()` in production code, are you?

Comment: @Kayaman not actually. in production it is going to be a static reference. You asked this beacause 'LogManager.getLogger( )' is a heavy call right?

Comment: Among other things, yes, and because it's just the wrong way. You can look at the source code of log4j2 to try and see what it's doing internally and what may cause the effect you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not thread safe. Logger is not logging initial messages, because it is configured by default to `ERROR` level, and then is reconfigured to `INFO`. You can check that by changing logging method in `calculate()` from `info()` to `error()` - you will receive all 3 messages.

To fix it, logger needs to be reconfigured before messing with threads.
For example, you can make a logger field:

```
private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
```

And use in calculate method like this:

```
public void calculate() {
  loger.info( "total is ..." );
}
```

Additionally, it will spare you a logger resolution by getLogger() method each time calculate() is invoked.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. very good point on log level `ERROR` and `INFO`. But I dont understand how it works when the method is synchronized ?. And yes when the logger is `final`(immutable) it can be accessed with multiple threads.

Comment: Details would require deeper dive into log4j2 code.
I can speculate, that it is due to forced local thread memory synchronisation by `synchronized`, and lack of it without `synchronized` wrapper; configuration may be setup in executor thread, but logging itself is performed in another (main, or logger) thread.
Again, it's just speculation, would require more log4j2 code reading.

Comment: Yes that could be the reason `main` thread waits continuously for that thread(configuration or logging thread) to be  finished.